# squarespace query only for home page

Tags: json, squarespace

I am using squarespace developer kit and going well. I am wanting to integrate some queries to display some very simple data form my blogs that will appear on my home page ONLY.

Not being very fluent in JSON, I am struggling to implement the query on the home page. I have it set up to display the data from the selected blog but it displays the data through each page.

I only want the data to be visible on the home page at the top. Not in the header but inside where all the content is.

Here is my query that works perfectly well

```
    <squarespace:query collection="feature-articles" limit="10">

  <li>
    {.repeated section items}
        <li><a href="{fullUrl}">{title}</a></li>
    {.end}
  </li>

</squarespace:query>
```

Can the data be inserted into a code block via the content manager so I can then insert into within the content or am I totally wrong in thinking that.

What I will then do is style/ add or edit the UI of the data into either a carousel or whatever is needed for the project.

I just need to know where to store the query so that it fits in with the content.

Appreciate any time.

Comment: I need a script to make sure when the page is loaded the query loads inside with the content, how would i make this script?

Answer (score 0):

Review the following link to see how you can edit a template file, to make different pages use different templates.

http://developers.squarespace.com/template-configuration/

Make a completely custom template just for your homepage then paste you code within your custom .region file as outlin ed in the above guide.

Here is the page about working with template pages:
http://developers.squarespace.com/layouts-regions/

Seeing as you know about , I have a feeling you might already know this, so you might want to be a bit more specific about how your displaying your code and I will gladly update my answer.